# Por que verde = azul + amarelo, mas no RGB amarelo = verde e vermelho?

Tags: cores, rgb

Por que a formação de cores no RGB não segue o mesmo padrão da natureza, e mesmo assim dá certo?

Por exemplo:

No RGB, amarelo = vemelho e verde: #FF0000 + #00FF00 = #FFFF00.
Mas se pegarmos um lápis de cor amarelo e outro azul (ou tintas, pincéis, etc.), e pintar uma mesma área, ela se torna verde (ou pelo menos algo parecido).

Os tons não são os mesmos, até porque depende da quantidade de amarelo ou azul, para formar o verde.

Isto é, o amarelo depende do verde, e em outro o verde depende do amarelo.

**NOTA:**
Entendo que as respostas irão pender para o lado da física e biologia. Mas sempre tive essa dúvida porque além de trabalhar com back-end, trabalho com front-end, e isso me ocorre muito frequentemente. Isso porque o sistema RGB não "fecha" muito o que aprendemos com a "tia de Artes" na escola. Então, não fica muito intuitivo na hora de chegar em uma cor ao desenhar uma página. Estou atrás do porque do sistema RGB ser diferente do outro, e ele ser o escolhido para ser aplicado em imagens e desenhos de aplicações. (Se não estou enganado, é estudado em Processamento de Imagens).

Comment: http://riftlabs.com/2010/09/how-rgb-light-works/

Comment: Luz emitida vs Luz refletida, creio...

Comment: A resposta dada pelo @brandizzi já esclarece a questão. Um caso é subtração de cores, o outro adição.

Comment: Para quem se interessar, aqui tem [um post interessante](http://blog.asmartbear.com/color-wheels.html) (em inglês) explicando como as cores "funcionam" de forma diferente: a) como tinta; b) como luz; c) como ondas eletromagnéticas; d) no nosso cérebro.

Comment: Estas não são as cores da natureza, mas sim as cores dos pintores "das antigas" e da "tia do primário". Não é muito científica a escolha destas cores, a do CMYK é mais precisa. Vale uma pesquisada no funcionamento da retina dos humanos, em especial dos cones e bastonetes. (lembrando que em outros seres vivos é diferente o espectro, e que há alguns casos em que pessoas tem diferente percepção destas cores e até mais variação de espectro).

Comment: A pergunta é interessante, mas será que é on-topic num site sobre programação? Tudo bem que parte do fato de RGB ser usado em monitores e por isso comum quando programamos, mas as respostas parecem ser sobre física, neurociência e até morfologia da retina!

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah, mas justo agora que eu ia perguntar "Será que o azul que eu vejo é igual ao azul que outras pessoas vêem?" /rofl

Comment: @Bacco a verdade é que o azul que vês, eu posso vê-lo de outra forma completamente diferente, a questão é que aquele "padrão" que vês associas a palavra azul :)

Comment: Essa pergunta não está descontextualizada quanto à programação, ela apenas se limita à Teoria das Cores que é, por exemplo, um dos pontos utilizados em algorítimos de reconhecimento de caracteres ou até mesmo de imagens (vide Google Image Search).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

O "padrão da natureza" de azul, vermelho e amarelo é, na verdade, uma base de [cores primárias subtrativas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cor_prim%C3%A1ria#Cores_prim.C3.A1rias_subtrativas). Cores primárias subtrativas formam outras cores através da **absorção** de luz. Por exemplo, se você mistura tintas amarela e azul, teremos uma cor verde mais escura, correto? Isto ocorre porque o novo pigmento absorve tanto as frequências amarela e azul - as frequências que sobram e são refletidas "causam" a sensação da cor verde. Assim sendo, quanto mais tinta você misturar, mais escuro o pigmento vai ficar, porque absorverá mais cores.

As telas de computadores, porém, não refletem luz - ao contrário, elas **emitem** luz. Neste caso, "misturar os pigmentos" implica na verdade em emitir luz em várias frequências. Isto significa que, quanto mais cores são emitidas, mais clara será a cor (porque haverá mais luz). Claro que a combinação não poderia ser a mesma das cores subtrativas - na verdade, é bem o contrário: para obter as combinações de [cores aditivas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cor_prim%C3%A1ria#Cores_prim.C3.A1rias_aditivas), basta fazer a "operação inversa" à das cores subtativas. Como bem diz a Wikipédia:

> As cores primárias aditivas mais usadas são as cores secundárias das cores subtrativas primárias mais comuns, e vice versa.

[image: Diagrama de sobreposições das cores primárias aditivas amarelo, vermelho e azul (Fonte: Wikimedia Commons)]

*Diagrama de sobreposições das cores primárias aditivas amarelo, vermelho e azul (Fonte: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Synthese+.svg))*

Como RGB serve principalmente para representar cores em monitores, ele usa cores primárias aditivas.

---

Agora, vale notar algo importante: embora a ensinem na escola, **uma base de cores subtrativas com vermelho, azul e amarelo é ruim**,  porque não é ortogonal. Você mesmo notou isso ao dizer que uma área pintada com amarelo e azul "se torna verde *(ou pelo menos algo parecido)*." Esta base é conhecida como [RYB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RYB) e é ensinada mais por motivos históricos e, talvez, didáticos do que por ser uma base eficiente.

Uma base cores primárias subtrativas muito melhor, e que é a mais usada na prática, são o amarelo, o magenta e o ciano (além do preto, para não desperdiçar tinta).

[image: Diagrama de sobreposições das cores primárias subtrativas amarelo, ciano e magenta (Fonte: Wikimedia Commons)]

*Diagrama de sobreposições das cores primárias subtrativas amarelo, ciano e magenta (Fonte: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CMY_ideal_version.svg))*

Essa base é conhecida como [CMYK](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) (do inglês "Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and Key (preto)") e é extremamente importante em design e impressão. Se você olhar o cartucho de uma impressora a tinta, provavelmente verá estas quatro cores. (O preto vai junto porque, embora possa ser composto em teoria com as outras cores, é uma muito usada e compensa ser mandado à parte, além de facilitar o escurecimento dos outros tons. Também pode ocorrer de haver cartuchos de outras cores, dependendo dos usos da impressora.)

[image: Repare nas quatro cores no canto inferior direito da imagem. (Fonte: Wikimedia Commons)]

*Repare nas quatro cores no canto inferior direito da imagem. (Fonte: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:HP_Business_Inkjet_1200n_-_Continuous_Ink_System_-_Printhead_shown_removed.jpg))*

---

[Este post](http://blog.ricbit.com/2009/06/as-batalhas-do-magenta.html) é uma fascinante exploração desse tema (e minha fonte principal :P )

Comment: O interessante é que a absorção das cores também explica o motivo de objetos escuros geralmente ficarem mais quentes a luz do sol (aquela velha história do carro preto x carro branco). Um objeto branco repele as cores, já um objeto preto absorve todos os espectros, que, de certa forma também são energia, o que acaba por fazer o corpo que absorveu mais cores se aquecer com mais facilidade.

Comment: Gostei da resposta, mas frisaria mais o fato das "cores da natureza" serem na verdade as cores "da tia do primário". Interessante seria mencionar dos cones e bastonetes na retina, que ficaria mais fácil de entender o motivo. De qq forma, +1

Comment: @Bacco Eu comentei no final sobre como estas cores não são uma boa base, mas concordo que isto merece mais ênfase. Tentei deixar mais claro isso. Só não entrei na questão dos bastonetes porque já fui muito além da minha área de experiência (sou daqueles que,se pudesse, só ficava no terminal de linha de comando :P)

Answer (score 24):

Basicamente por se tratarem de sistemas de cores diferentes, [aditivas (RGB)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB) e [subtrativas (CMYK)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK).

### Cores aditivas

Usado em monitores, é gerada pela mistura de vários cumprimentos de ondas luminosas. No processo aditivo o preto é gerado pela ausência de cor e o branco é a mistura de todas elas.

#### Modelo de cor RGB

O modelo de cores RGB define as cores utilizando os componentes:

- Vermelho - Red **(R)**
- Verde - Green **(G)**
- Azul - Blue **(B)**

O componente RGB gera a cor conforme a quantidade de luz vermelha, verde e azul, que variam de 0 a 255. Quando é adicionado o valor total de todas as cores, ou seja `RGB(255,255,255)` é gerado a cor branca, e quando não há nenhuma lu, no caso`RGB(0,0,0)` forma a cor preta.
[image: Sistema de cores RGB]

### Cores subtrativas

Usados nas impressões e pinturas. Possui como cores primárias:

- Azul Ciano **(C)**
- Magenta **(M)**
- Amarelo - *Yellow* **(Y)**
- Preto - Black **(K)**

No processo subtrativo cores da luz branca são absolvidas, quando a luz branca atinge um objeto parte é absolvida e parte é refletida, ao contrário do RGB, o branco é ausência de cor e o preto a mistura de todas.

[image: sistema de cores CMYK]

Os materiais impressos são reproduzidos usando o modelo de cor CMYK. Ao combinar ciano, magenta, amarelo e preto, de forma que o valor de cada componente seja 100, o resultado é preto. Quando o valor de cada componente é 0, o resultado é branco puro.

#### Conclusão

Quando falamos de cor, temos a cor obtida aditivamente (luz / RGB) ou a cor obtida subtrativamente (pigmento / CMYK). Por isso a diferença na combinação.